# Change the header of the website if viewed from iPhone device?

Tags: php, iphone, mobile

I have a website that looks pretty good on mobile (iPhone devices). but the only thing that is off putting is the header when viewed on mobile!

the website is written in PHP. and the header of the site is template based. its called header.php in template folder.

i was wandering if it is possible to only change the header.php of the website if someone is viewing the site from a mobile phone instead of creating the whole site for mobile devices (mobile friendly website)?

I know I can divert the users to the mobile version of the website if i wanted to but I rather just change the header.php if someone's viewing it from a handset.

Thanks

**EDIT**

WOW GUYS, i'm spoilt for choices now. Thank you very much for all the answers.

can i select more than one answer here?

Comment: Check the user agent and serve a different header if from mobile.

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone, As i said, i know how to redirect the users to a mobile version of the site. that is not my question!!

Comment: Use this, simple and easy: https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

Comment: I know David but once you have determined if it is a mobile or not then you can include a different header surely??

Comment: cheers Peter. Voted as useful comment. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of [php-mobile-detect](https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/)?

Makes it real easy to do this kind of stuff.

```
include 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
if($detect->isiPhone()){
    // require different header
} else {
    // require standard header
}
```

I would plug it into a `$_SESSION` variable and check it with `if(!isset($_SESSION['iPhone']))` so its only called once. I do this kind of thing for different mobile operating system versions too, its very handy and they keep it up to date.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<?php
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad')) {
  include "mobile_header.php";
} else {
  include "desktop_header.php";
}

?>
```

**EDIT** thanks to @silentboy for pointing my mistake. changed.

Comment: That is a nice example but the question is to about a inclution of header.php not site title. However +1 for working example

Answer (score 1):

You can use a device detection library for this and conditionally display the proper header file.  Here is a good one:  http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/.

Answer (score 1):

Parse `$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];` for iPhone related strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
{
// display mobile header
}   
else{
// display standard header
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the server-side solutions that were just proposed or you can use media-queries to change the styles of the header to fit mobile.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  ...
}
```

Use this to add styles that are optimized for mobile. Either change the width, padding, sizes, etc. or you can hide certain markup that you don't want visible on mobile devices.

Just another option. :)

Comment: I do not know how to add a php file with css. Can you give an example?

Comment: You don't need to edit your php file. You just need to update your css file to re-stylize your header for mobile. Basically, you can add as much CSS into the @media block. Those styles will only be rendered on devices with max-width 480px and a screen. You can customize these as much as you like. http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/